Como puedo redireccionar a un archivo html desde JS
Basicamente necesito redireccionar a un documento html desde el indice, lo quiero hacer con js porque creo que es lo mas optimo para la situacion, pero acepto cualquier cosa

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Puedes utilizar una etiqueta meta en el <head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com/">

Donde está el 0 (cero) es la cantidad de segundos para que se reproduzca la redirección

Puedes agregar este codigo en tu html:
 <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
          window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        });
    </script>

Cuando cargue todo el documento, hace una redireccion, tambien puede ser otro html.
<script>
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
          window.location.href = "contacto.html";
     });
</script>

